# Scrollable paragraph having limited height to its parent

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to make `P` to be able to take more text than the height can contain, just so the text can be scrolled down to be read. `DIV CLASS="others"` has the right height I want. (500px)

The problem is, when I use the `overflow: scroll` function it goes all the way to the bottom of the page.

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention I want the titles "News" and "Products" to be without the scroll bar.

Thanks.

```css
.others {
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 70%;
background-color: #d0d0d0;
height: 500px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 40px 15% 20px 15%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.others div {
width: 400px;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin: 0px 15px;
}

.others #news {
background-color: black;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}

.others #products {
background-color: black;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}

.others a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none !important;
}

.others #newsfeed, #productsfeed {
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px 0px;
background-color: lightgreen;
}

.others p {
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px 10px;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 800px;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<DIV CLASS="others">
  <DIV ID="news">
 <A HREF="#"><H3 ID="newsfeed">News</H3></A>
 <P>News will come here.</P>
  </DIV>
  <DIV ID="products">
 <A HREF="#"><H3 ID="productsfeed">Products</H3></A>
 <P>Cool photos here.</P>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Why have you set `height: 800px;` on inner paragraphs then? That causes the issue.

Comment: Im trying to demonstrate if I had a lot of text and it would be up to 800px. Or will the normal text be differently represented on the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949960/overflow-propertys-scroll-bar-goes-through-the-bottom-although-height-should-be#comment40626634_25949960), the issue is caused by specifying an explicit height to the inner paragraphs.

Besides, in order to make the inner paragraphs respect the `height` of their parents *(`#news` and `#products` flex items which have the same height of their flex container, the `.other`)* you could change the `display` type of the parents to `flex` as well and set their `flex-direction` to `column`.

And then give `flex: 1;` to the paragraphs as follows:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/1zdcc7t6/)**

```css
#news, #products {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#news p, #products p {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto; /* up to you */
}
```

As a **side-note**: make sure you have included the old (prefixed) syntax of flexbox as well for the sake of browser support. You could use tools like [Auto Prefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You need a containing `div` on the paragraphs, then set `overflow: scroll;` and `height: 460px;` on that container (or whatever height you need to have it contained within the 500px tall `.others` block).

You'd also need to make sure your `.others div` styling doesn't apply to that container - in my example below, I changed that selector to `.others > div` to only select immediate children of `.others`. And you should remove the `height: 800px;` from the inner paragraphs, as mentioned by Hashem Qolami.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2g3mcm3g/2/)

Comment: Thank you as well for the answer. Both were useful :)